# Rails query include not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations

In my app I have 3 models: Item, Category and Categorization defined as below:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :description

  has_many :categorizations
  has_many :categories, :through => :categorizations
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :description, :parent, :children, :items, :parent_id  

  has_many :children, :class_name => "Category", :foreign_key => "parent_id", :dependent => :nullify
  belongs_to :parent, :class_name => "Category"

  has_many :categorizations
  has_many :items, :through => :categorizations
end

class Categorization < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :category, :item

  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :item

end
```

However, doing this:

```
 Category.where(:parent_id => self.id).includes(:items)
```

won't return me the items associated to the category. What am I missing here?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "won't return me the items associated to the category."? What do you expect to happen and what happens?

Comment: I was expecting that I could access the :items in the categories obtained by where, but :items is empty.

Comment: When using `includes` you could end up with empty `items`. If you only want to retrieve categories that have items you have to use `joins`, which does an inner join.

Comment: @Rui Have you managed to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Category.where(parent_id: id).joins(:items)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
Category.where(:parent_id => id).collect(&:items)
```

It will return the items of all categories matching the `where` clause.

Comment: The whole point of using `includes` is preventing N+1 queries. This will execute N+1 queries.

Comment: Then you should start from `Item`. Try this, `Item.joins(:categorizations => :category).where('categories.parent_id' => id)`

Comment: No, you should just use `includes`. There is nothing wrong with it.

Comment: `Category.where(:parent_id => self.id).includes(:categorizations => :item)`